# Sending !Send Payload type to function expecting Send

Tags: rust, rust-tokio, actix-web

Actix web has a [Payload](https://docs.rs/actix-web/4.2.1/actix_web/web/struct.Payload.html#) type which is `!Send`. I want to use an async function which take a stream and performs some manipulation. This function's signature looks like:

```
async fn stream_handler(
    mut bytes: bytes: &mut (impl Stream<Item = Result<Bytes, impl Error + Send>> Send + Unpin)
) { ... }
```

The problem is that I can cannot pass this `!Send` Payload type. I'm not sure what the best approach would be here. Since actix generally assumes things are `!Send` and leverages `LocalSet` for the single threaded behavior, is this just a fundamental problem that I've encountered, and I need to write my own `!Send` stream_handler?

Is there a design pattern to deal with this that is commonly known in Rust?